# maven generate eclipse project for custom packaging

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, packaging

for a project I'm working on, I've defined a custom maven packaging, and the associated lifecycle (through the definition of a `components.xml` and the definition of a `LifecycleMapping`).

Obviously, this packaging corresponds to a specific development, for which a plugin has been created in Eclipse. What I would like to do is configure Eclipse according to my pom.xml content.

I've obviously looked at [Customizable build lifecycle](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Customizable+build+lifecycle+mapping+for+m2e+extensions+developers), but I'm more than confused by provided information.

From what I understand, I must define in my target project a build plugin, in which i'll add configuration elements specific to my project. As an example, having a configurator called `mycompany.mydev.MyEclipseConfigurator`, I'll have to write

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.maven.ide.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
          <mappingId>customizable</mappingId>
          <configurators>
            <configurator id='mycompany.mydev.MyEclipseConfigurator'/>
          </configurators>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, previously mentionned documentation refers to deprecated version of maven eclipse plugin.

[The most up-to-date version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/provide-project-natures-and-build-commands.html) clearly states how to configure eclipse project from within maven pom.xml by specifying project's nature and builders.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had with our custom packaging, is that Maven did not recognize the project as being Java-based, hence the Maven Eclipse Plugin did not generate the right entries in the `.project` file, and did not generate a `.classpath`.

The first thing can be corrected by adding the right build commands and natures in the POM, but that still does not give you a `.classpath`.

The solution is to add the following fragment to your `components.xml`:

> ```
>   <component>
>         <role>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler
>         </role>
>         <role-hint>(fill in your own packaging)</role-hint>
>         <implementation>
>             org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler
>         </implementation>
>         <configuration>
>             <type>(fill in your own packaging)</type>
>             <extension>(choose war or jar if required)</extension>
>             <language>java</language>
>             <addedToClasspath>true</addedToClasspath>
>         </configuration>
>     </component>
> ```

With this addition, the MEP will treat your project as a normal JAR or WAR project and generate the expected Eclipse configuration for it.